# Konkqueror and KHTML engine - disable right click

Tags: javascript, html, debian, konqueror

I'm using Konqueror 4.14.25 with **KHTML** engine and cannot disable the right click (the context menu). I've tried

`document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {  event.preventDefault()  });`

but it seems that the contextmenu event does not exist. Using **webkit** engine i am able to disable the right click! Due to the project tasks I am forced to use Konqueror browser with KHTML engine. Any idea how can I disable the right click?

Comment: You can try to use capture mode, add the third argument (`true`) to the parameters of `addEventListener`.

Comment: I already tried with third arg but won't work.

Comment: Did you also call `event.stopPropagation`? If the event really doesn't fire at all, you could try to use a click event, check `event.which` and if it's right button (check the correct value, it's browser dependent), prevent the default action and stop propagation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many unsuccessful combinations and tries I finally found one that should work:

```
        document.oncontextmenu = function() {
           return false;
        }
```

Also

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

won't works. The reason is unknown. khtml does not recognize it.